# Problem while using isinstance of imported class

Tags: python

I have a problem while using `isinstance` when checking if an argument is an instance of a class that I've imported from another file. I tried to change `*` to Register, but then the error is that

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Register' from partially initialized module 'sample.dziennik' (most likely due to a circular import)`

If I have `*` the error is that `NameError: Register name is not defined`

Is there any possibility to work it out?

`___init__` code:

```
from sample.dziennik import *

def checkIfGoodValues(id,firstName,lastName,register,subjects,warnings):
    #check if id is int
    if type(id) != int:
        return False
    if type(firstName) != str:
        return False
    if type(lastName) != str:
        return False
    if not isinstance(register,Register):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

some of Register class if needed:

```
class Register:
    def __init__(self, students=None, subjects=None):
        if subjects is None:
            subjects = []
        if students is None:
            students = []
        self.students = students
        self.subjects = subjects
```

Comment: Are these all the imports in both files? It seems you might have a circular import situation

Comment: Why do you have that much code in your `__init__`? That is usually very discouraged, as you can move it to the module implementation itself. You see, you're trying to import something in `__init__` (the Register class). In Python, it means it will run everything in the `__init__` file before. But your `__init__` wants to import Register... well, you've got yourself into a circular import situation

Comment: I'd advise to move the code to another place. Either the same file as Register, or another one, with a meaningful name. Another thing is: use `isinstance(var, type_)` in all cases in place of `type(var) == type_`. It will properly handle subclasses and is the recommended solution

Comment: I'm using "Sample Python Project". I don't know in which file I should test my classes. In my sample directory there are: all classes (also register), __init__. 
The second problem I'm facing is that if I print ANYTHING, it prints twice in __init__. How can I work it out?

Comment: By posting a clear [mre]

Comment: What is "Sample Python Project"? It doesn't really narrow it down for other people. Also, the question about printing is exactly that: another question; should be placed as a new one. It seems to me that the problem here is not imports per se, but instead about project structure. Please edit your question adding the directory tree of the project, and try to provide a minimal reproducible example